# No extension method called open in ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I wanted use servicestack.ormlite to connect to the database.But I get this error even after adding the refrence from Nuget.

I used this command to install

> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer

This is the error thrown

> 'ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Open' and no extension method 'Open' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqliteDialect.Provider);
//I get error when I call open method
using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.Open())
{

}
```

Comment: One doubt I have in your code is you install package "ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" but try to use SqlliteDialect.Provider. SqliteDialect enum is not available in the package you mentioned. I tried doing it and if failed compilation with saying "SqliteDialect" can't be reconized as a type. 
I tried installing package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows" and code work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IDbConnectionFactory.Open()` extension method is defined in [OrmLiteConnectionFactoryExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/d92f5d487891574ed5426b40836bfd123d3ab48a/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs#L153) that's defined under `ServiceStack.OrmLite` namespace so you need to import:

```
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Extension method Open does not take any argument?

I checked the source code of OrmLiteConnectionFactory Extensions on git and there is no extension method with name Open for OrmLiteConnectionFactory which take no argument. 
Extension method Open of OrmLiteConnectionFactory takes one string argument "nammedconnection".

Following is the git link of the source code.
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs

So I am sure calling Open with proper argument would resolve your issue.

Thanks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: In that case you might not be using the same version of ormlite which is used in the example of your link.

Comment: Are you getting compile time error or runtime error?